# Java 8 mapToInt and toIntFunction examples

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am testing the new major update from Java (Java 8) and it is very interesting. I am using streams; in particular I am using this simple code.

```
private void getAvg()
{
    final ArrayList<MyPerson>persons = new ArrayList<>
    (Arrays.asList(new MyPerson("Ringo","Starr"),new MyPerson("John","Lennon"),new MyPerson("Paul","Mccartney"),new MyPerson("George","Harrison")));                
    final OptionalDouble average = persons.stream().filter(p->p.age>=40).mapToInt(p->p.age).average();
    average.ifPresent(System.out::println);        
    return;
}            
private class MyPerson
{
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final String name,lastName;
    private int age;
    public MyPerson(String name,String lastName){this.name = name;this.lastName = lastName;this.age=random.nextInt(100);}    
    public MyPerson(String name,String lastName,final int age){this(name,lastName);this.age=age;}    
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public String getLastName(){return lastName;}                   
    public int getAge(){return age;}        
}
```

In this example I understand very clear but later I have seen also can accomplish it in this way:

```
final OptionalDouble average = persons.stream().filter(p->p.age>=40)
.mapToInt(MyPerson::getAge).average();
average.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

I have checked the method **toIntFunction** and in fact have the following signature:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ToIntFunction<T> {

/**
 * Applies this function to the given argument.
 *
 * @param value the function argument
 * @return the function result
 */
int applyAsInt(T value);
}
```

As I can see the applyAsInt have a input and returns an int as long as I understand.

This code:

```
MyPerson::getAge
```

calls:

```
public int getAge(){return age;}//please correct me at this point
```

My question is: the method `getAge` have not parameters and returns a **int** but the *toIntFunction* receive a parameter - this is the part I don't understand.

The parameter from `toIntFunction` is inferred or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember a method reference is just a shortcut for a lambda. So an instance method reference is a lambda that calls that method on the argument. The type of the argument is the class given in the method reference. It helps to "unwrap" it.

```
MyPerson::getAge
```

Unwrap to a lambda:

```
(MyPerson p) -> p.getAge()
```

Unwrap to an anonymous class:

```
new ToIntFunction<MyPerson>() {
    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(MyPerson p) {
        return p.getAge();
    }
}
```

With a static method reference, the signature must match exactly, that is, the static method takes a `T` and returns an `int`. With an instance method reference, the parameter `T` of the lambda is the object the method gets called on.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `MyPerson::getAge` is like a pointer to `MyPerson`s getAge() method, which returns an `int`. So `value.getAge()` gets invoked in `int applyAsInt(MyPerson value);`.
In other words: You just tell the stream, that it should use `getAge()`s return value from it's current `MyPerson` iteration variable to construct <strike>another collection</strike> an [IntStream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

Comment: If that's the case, which implementation of `applyAsInt` is used?

Comment: It seem's like you're the one who provides that implementation with specifying `MyPerson:getAge`, which returns.. that integer you look for ;)

Comment: Your second sentence is confusing. The `int` is given as an argument to `applyAsInt`?

Comment: I initially thought that, but Radiodef's answer seems to be correct. The argument is an `MyPerson` object.